# How do I convert this SQL to use joins?

Tags: sql, mysql

How do I convert this SQL to use joins?

```
SELECT 
   V.V_CONTACT, V.V_PHONE 
FROM 
   VENDOR AS V, 
   PRODUCT AS P 
WHERE 
   P.P_CODE = 'P1' AND 
   V.V_CODE = P.V_CODE;
```

Comment: Technically, this query already does a relational equijoin operation, but with the original SQL syntax.  The newer ANSI JOIN syntax Mitch provided makes the join explicit, and is clearer and less prone to cause errors.

Comment: @Jim: They're both ANSI syntax.  The older syntax is in SQL-89.  The `JOIN` keyword and related syntax was introduced in SQL-92, but the older syntax is still part of the standard to preserve backward compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT    
   V.V_CONTACT, V.V_PHONE 
FROM
   VENDOR AS V 
   JOIN PRODUCT AS P ON V.V_CODE = P.V_CODE
WHERE    
   P.P_CODE = 'P1';
```